# How can I get the predicted class using the probability in AdaBoostClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, probability, adaboost

I try to get the predicted class using the predicted probability, but the accuracy changes drastically, given the class [-1, 1] respectively.

Here is the code I use to convert the probability to predicted class.

```py
y_pred_prob = []
for i in Y_prob:
    if i[0] > i[1]:
        y_pred_prob.append(-1)
    else:
        y_pred_prob.append(1)
```

When I use the predicted class the accuracy is 0.8983, but when I use the `y_pred_prob` the accuracy changes to 0.6241

Comment: Is it a binary classification problem or multi-class?

Comment: @Matt it is binary

Comment: Have you compared y_pred_prob with the predicted class? Most likely they do not look the same and this is what you need to figure out

Comment: @MaximeKan I have, and yes they are not the same.

Comment: @RianJunianto then please show how you defined Y_prob and how you called model.predict to get the predicted class

Comment: @MaximeKan `Y_prob = model.predict_prob(x_test)`